# Grails Hibernate Exception: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: hibernate, exception, grails

I'm trying to map a one to one relationship between two domains where TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap has a Foreign PK which comes from TemplateOutput. When I go to save the instance of ToTransDisplayMap I get the following error:

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException
attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property 
[TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap.templateOutput]

The code for both domains are below starting with TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap followed by TemplateOutput:

```
class TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap {

static belongsTo = [templateOutput:TemplateOutput, templateStep:TemplateStep]
TemplateOutput templateOutput

Long id
String tsStep
String toParameterName
String displayLabel
String defaultValue
String toMapParameter
String sqlQuery
String selectClause
String whereClause
Long   fetchCount
String transTable
String columnName
String displayed
String xPath
String isNameValue

static mapping = {

    table 'TO_TRANS_DISP_MAP'
    version false

    id              column: 'TO_SYSID', generator: 'foreign', params:      [property:'templateOutput']

    templateOutput  column: 'TO_SYSID', insertable: false, updateable: false
    templateStep    column: 'TO_TS_SYSID'
    tsStep          column: 'TS_STEP'
    toParameterName column: 'TO_PARAM_NAME'
    displayLabel    column: 'DISPLAY_LABEL'
    defaultValue    column: 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
    toMapParameter  column: 'TO_MAP_PARAM'
    sqlQuery        column: 'SQL_QUERY'
    selectClause    column: 'SELECT_CLAUSE'
    whereClause     column: 'WHERE_CLAUSE'
    fetchCount      column: 'FETCH_COUNT'
    transTable      column: 'TRANS_TABLE'
    columnName      column: 'COLUMN_NAME'
    xPath           column: 'XPATH'
    isNameValue     column: 'IS_NAME_VALUE'

}

static constraints = {
    tsStep          (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    toParameterName (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    displayLabel    (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    defaultValue    (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    toMapParameter  (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    sqlQuery        (maxSize:1000, blank:true, nullable:true)
    selectClause    (maxSize:100,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    whereClause     (maxSize:1000, blank:true, nullable:true)
    fetchCount      (maxSize:3,    blank:true, nullable:true)
    transTable      (maxSize:250,  blank:true, nullable:true)
    columnName      (maxSize:30,   blank:true, nullable:true)
    displayed       (maxSize:1,    blank:true, nullable:true)
    xPath           (maxSize:2000, blank:true, nullable:true)
    isNameValue     (maxSize:3,    blank:true, nullable:true)
    templateStep                  (blank:true, nullable:true)
   }
}




class TemplateOutput {

static belongsTo = [templateStep:TemplateStep]
static hasOne = [templateOutputTransDisplayMap:TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap]

Long id
String parameterName
String usage
String mappingParameter 

static mapping = {

    table 'TEMPLATE_OUTPUT'
    version false

    id               column: 'SYSID', generator: 'assigned'
    templateStep     column: 'TS_SYSID'
    parameterName    column: 'PARAMETER_NAME'
    mappingParameter column: 'MAPPING_PARAMETER'

}

static constraints = {
    parameterName    (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    usage            (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    mappingParameter (maxSize:250, blank:true, nullable:true)
    templateStep                  (blank:true, nullable:true)
    templateOutputTransDisplayMap (blank:true, nullable:true)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try printing inside the domain ToTransDisplayMap println templateOutput?templateOutput.id:0.And check the result.Then we can proceed further.

Comment: It prints TemplateOutput.id:

Comment: I saw your domain TemplateOutputTransDisplayMap again and found you have defined one to one mapping twice . The below code lines is the problem ..static belongsTo = [templateOutput:TemplateOutput, templateStep:TemplateStep]
TemplateOutput templateOutput --Remove this.

Comment: From the above comment I want to say either remove TemplateOutput templateOutput  or belongTo =[...]

Comment: You mean TemplateOutput templateOutput below the static belongsTo line correct? I removed that line and the problem still persists. For some reason it's not getting the ID from TemplateOutput correctly.

Comment: Tried your suggestion @MadhuBose but the problem persists unfortunately.

Comment: Could you share your code when you are binding the data?

Comment: Problem solved, I missed out templateInput:templateInput under create in the controller.